# Get Image from my Django application in flutter

Tags: python, django, api, flutter

I'm trying to display images in my flutter application from my Django website.[djangoApi](https://pure-eyrie-09235.herokuapp.com/photoAPI/)
but the problem in my flutter i can't see my pictures.
(i don't know if the problem in my Django or flutter app)

**Flutter app:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
 final response =
    await client.get('https://pure-eyrie-09235.herokuapp.com/photoAPI');

 // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
 }

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Photo {
  
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String desc; 

  Photo({this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl, this.desc});

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Photo(
      // albumId: json['albumId'] as int,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      title: json['title'] as String,
      imageUrl: json['image'] as String,
      desc: json['desc'] as String,
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'My Photo Sharing!';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
        );
      }
    }

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(title,),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
   body: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
     future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

      return snapshot.hasData
          ? PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data)
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
       },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Photo> photos;

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 1,
      ),
      itemCount: photos.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return Image.network(
        photos[index].imageUrl,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        height: 60.0, width: 60.0);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Note: I'm just trying to understand how to consummate from API if i made my own app**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, The answer should be like this:

```
class Photo {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String desc;

  Photo({this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl, this.desc});

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Photo(
      // albumId: json['albumId'] as int,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      title: json['title'] as String,
      imageUrl: json['image'] as String,
      desc: json['description'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

and in build method PhotosList class should be return:

```
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.network(photos[index].imageUrl,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          height: 60,
          width: 60,),
        Text(photos[index].title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
      ],
    );
```

After that everything will be okay.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are making two mistakes in the Image.network it should be photos[index].url not title and in Photo.fromJson it should be json['image'] not json['url'] (I cheked your api).

Here is a working method that can replace your fetchPhotos without needing for parsePhotos (I got rid of the http.Client ) :

```
Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos() async {
 http.Response res = await http.get('https://pure-eyrie-09235.herokuapp.com/photoAPI');
 var parsed = jsonDecode(res) ; 
 List<Photo> photos = [] ; 
 for (var photo in parsed) 
    photos.add(Photo.fromJson(photo)) ; 
 return photos ; 

}
```

Comment: I solved my problem by adding also the ( desc: json['description'] as String, ) in the Photo class.
also, The method you wrote does not work because of confusion between the http request and the string input which is the url of API.
so it's best is to keep my function.
Thank you For your time.